# switch button works on the second click - Android

Tags: android

I added a switch button to my app and created a setOnCheckChangeListener the will pop up toast message..

But it works only after the second click.

Any ideas?

**MainActivity:**

```
    public void checkSwitch (View view)
{
    addBeeps.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked)
            {
                beeps = true;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"beeps is True",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else
            {
                beeps = false;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"beeps is False",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Are you setting the initial state for the switch button? addBeeps.setChecked(true)

Comment: When are you calling `checkSwitch()`? Need more code.

Comment: @GeorgeArokiam Hi George, I believe it is set in the method itself when created. boolean isChecked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in xml file which contains `addBeeps` switch you are using this code.

```
<Switch
        android:id="@+id/addBeeps"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="checkSwitch"/>
```

**Root cause:** For the first time when you check the switch, a listener will be set on it and do nothing, the second time when you check the switch again the listener is triggered and the Toast showed.

**Solution:** Here is a solution for you.

**Remove** `onClick` from the switch in xml file

```
<Switch
        android:id="@+id/addBeeps"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**Delete** or **comment-out** `checkSwitch` method from `MainActivity` and move set listener block code to `onCreate` method.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addBeeps = findViewById(R.id.addBeeps);

        // TODO: Put set listener block code here
        addBeeps.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    beeps = true;
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "beeps is True", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    beeps = false;
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "beeps is False", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // TODO: Delete or comment-out this method
//    public void checkSwitch(View view) {
//        addBeeps.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
//                if (isChecked) {
//                    beeps = true;
//                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "beeps is True", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                } else {
//                    beeps = false;
//                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "beeps is False", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                }
//            }
//        });
//    }
```

Comment: OH YES!!!
Thank you I was struggling with this issue for 3 days and 2 nights!

Thank you SO MUCH for the extended explanation!

Comment: Glad to hear that. Happy coding :)